# How to choose pixel value in case of nearest neighbor image down scaling

Tags: matrices, algorithms, image-processing

I am working on implementing a fast algorithm for image resizing (more generally 2D array of numbers resizing).

It is supposed to be fast, and **should not add new values** (meaning the result 2D array should not contain numbers which are not present in the original array, so exit bilinear, bicubic interpolation etc).

With these specification, Nearest Neighbor algorithm seems like the way to go but there is something that tickles me in the case of downsizing:

When down-sizing by a factor N, the value of a given pixel in the destination array has to be picked from a given NxN region in the source array. With the classical approach of Nearest Neighbor algorithm, it is always the top left value of the NxN region which is picked regarless of the values in the region. Are algorithm know for handling this with a "finer" touch WITHOUT adding new values in the results ? (pick the median value of the region for instance).

Maybe an optimized way of downscaling could be:

1. Median filter with NxN kernel on the original image
2. Classical Nearest Neighbor downscaling

[image]

Comment: (A) If we have grey-scale , we might use median , while with RBG , there is no clear median without introducing a new value. (B) Alternative : we can count & use the most common value in the Area.

Comment: If you want fast, then the original algorithm is your best bet. If you want the most accurate without introducing new values then use the median - the value for which half of the other values are $\ge$ it, while the other half are $\le$ to it (this will be ambiguous if there are an even number of values to consider, but you can pick the upper of the two possible values in that case - or the lower, the choice is yours). But this will be significantly slower than the algorithm above, as you have to look at every pixel of the original image and process them.